# Java Writer stopping after single write

Tags: java, writer

I'm looking to read the contents of a URL and write them to file, this is working as expected but it's only writing it a single time even though the program console shows multiple lines.

Code:

```
PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("the-file-name.txt", "UTF-8");
while(true) {
    URL oracle = new URL("https://linkToData.com");
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(oracle.openStream()));

    String inputLine;
    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
        writer.println(inputLine);
        System.out.println(inputLine);
    }
    writer.close();
```

The data in the URL refreshes constantly so there should be different data each time as the console print shows but it's only writing the first instance to file.

Comment: Have you tried calling `writer.flush()` before closing the output stream?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is `writer.close()`! If you want to write the file anew every time, you have to reopen the `Writer` each time.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to append file each time you have to flush writer instead of closing and close at the end.

```
PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("the-file-name.txt", "UTF-8");
while(condition) {
    URL oracle = new URL("https://linkToData.com");
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new  InputStreamReader(oracle.openStream()));

    String inputLine;
    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
        writer.println(inputLine);
        System.out.println(inputLine);
    }
    writer.flush();

}
writer.close();
```